# I have created my database file on my computer, why is my table not being created below?

Tags: python, sqlite

I was able to create the database file, was not able to create the table. I want to run everything through Python and not terminal. I have installed SQLite through the terminal. I am on a MacOS (High Sierra)

```
#THIS PYTHON FILE CREATES THE DATABASE
import sqlite3
#Creates the Database File
sqlite_file = '/Users/rebecca/Desktop/Movie Database/MovieDatabase '
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()
#closes the database door after completeing operations 'conn.close()'
#make changes or updates and save to database conn.commit()''conn.close()'

#THIS PYTHON FILE SHOULD CREATE THE TABLE IN THE DATABASE
import sqlite3

#Connecting to the database file
sqlite_file = '/Users/rebecca/Desktop/Movie Database/MovieDatabase '
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()

db = sqlite3.connect('MovieDatabase .db')

CREATE TABLE movietable (movie TEXT REQUIRED, actor TEXT REQUIRED,     rating INTEGER, viewed BOOLEAN, watchagain BOOLEAN);


 #CREATE A TABLE IN THE MOVIE DATABASE
```

Comment: FYI: There is a space between your DB name and extension (.db)  on line `db = sqlite3 ...`

Comment: It's not enough to write SQL code into your Python file. You have to use `cursor.execute(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the statement:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE movietable (movie TEXT REQUIRED, actor TEXT REQUIRED, rating INTEGER, viewed BOOLEAN, watchagain BOOLEAN)")
conn.commit()
```

Also, you can use the sqlite3 command "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" to prevent errors if the table already exists (or use a Python try block if you'd rather handle that error yourself instead of just ignore it).

You should also think about creating a primary key for your table so you don't insert the same movie by accident more than once -- Perhaps create an id for your movies as well.